# Buildroot 2015 Fails glibc

Tags: ubuntu, glibc

When I try to use buildroot, Glibc fails to compile with this error:

```
 checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/build/glibc-2.20/build':
 configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
 See `config.log' for more details
 make: *** [/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/build/glibc-2.20/.stamp_configured] Error 1
```

my config.log:

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by GNU C Library configure (see version.h), which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.68.  Invocation command line was

  $ /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/build/glibc-2.20/./configure ac_cv_path_BASH_SHELL=/bin/bash libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes libc_cv_ssp=no --target=x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --with-fp --with-pkgversion=Buildroot --without-cvs --disable-profile --without-gd --enable-obsolete-rpc --with-headers=/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = SamUbuntu
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 3.16.0-43-generic
uname -s = Linux
uname -v = #58~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 22 10:21:20 UTC 2015

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = unknown
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/bin
PATH: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/sbin
PATH: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin
PATH: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/sbin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/sbin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /sbin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /usr/games
PATH: /usr/local/games
PATH: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin
PATH: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin
PATH: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin
PATH: /home/sam/bin
PATH: /usr/local/java/jre1.8.0_45/bin


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:2343: checking build system type
configure:2357: result: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
configure:2377: checking host system type
configure:2390: result: x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu
configure:2419: checking for x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc
configure:2446: result: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc
configure:2715: checking for C compiler version
configure:2724: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc --version >&5
/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/build/glibc-2.20/./configure: line 2726: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:2735: $? = 127
configure:2724: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc -v >&5
/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/build/glibc-2.20/./configure: line 2726: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:2735: $? = 127
configure:2724: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc -V >&5
/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/build/glibc-2.20/./configure: line 2726: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:2735: $? = 127
configure:2724: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc -qversion >&5
/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/build/glibc-2.20/./configure: line 2726: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:2735: $? = 127
configure:2740: checking for suffix of object files
configure:2762: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc -c -O2   conftest.c >&5
/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/build/glibc-2.20/./configure: line 2764: /home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc: No such file or directory
configure:2766: $? = 127
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Library"
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glibc"
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION "(see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Library (see version.h)"
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/"
| #define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/"
| #define PKGVERSION "(Buildroot) "
| #define REPORT_BUGS_TO "<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>"
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:2780: error: in `/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/build/glibc-2.20/build':
configure:2782: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=set
ac_cv_env_CC_value=/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value='-O2 '
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPP_set=set
ac_cv_env_CPP_value=/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-cpp
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value='-O2 '
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=set
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-g++
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=set
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=set
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu
ac_cv_host=x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu
ac_cv_path_BASH_SHELL=/bin/bash
ac_cv_prog_CC=/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc
libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes
libc_cv_ssp=no

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AR='/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-ar'
AS='/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-as'
ASFLAGS_config=''
AUTOCONF=''
AWK=''
BASH_SHELL=''
BISON=''
BUILD_CC=''
CC='/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-gcc'
CFLAGS='-O2 '
CPP='/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-cpp'
CPPFLAGS=''
CPPUNDEFS=''
CXX='/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-g++'
CXXFLAGS='-O2 '
CXX_SYSINCLUDES=''
DEFINES=''
DEFS=''
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
INSTALL_DATA=''
INSTALL_INFO=''
INSTALL_PROGRAM=''
INSTALL_SCRIPT=''
LD='/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-ld'
LDFLAGS=''
LIBGD=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LN_S=''
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKE=''
MAKEINFO=''
MSGFMT=''
NM='/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-nm'
OBJCOPY='/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-objcopy'
OBJDUMP='/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-objdump'
OBJEXT=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT='http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/'
PACKAGE_NAME='GNU C Library'
PACKAGE_STRING='GNU C Library (see version.h)'
PACKAGE_TARNAME='glibc'
PACKAGE_URL='http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/'
PACKAGE_VERSION='(see version.h)'
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERL='/usr/bin/perl'
PKGVERSION='(Buildroot) '
PKGVERSION_TEXI='(Buildroot) '
READELF='/home/sam/buildroot/buildroot-2015.05/output/host/usr/bin/x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu-readelf'
RELEASE=''
REPORT_BUGS_TEXI='@uref{http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html}'
REPORT_BUGS_TO='<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>'
SED=''
SHELL='/bin/bash'
SYSINCLUDES=''
VERSION=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
add_on_subdirs=''
add_ons=''
all_warnings=''
base_machine=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
bindnow=''
build='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_alias='x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_nscd=''
build_os='linux-gnu'
build_pt_chown=''
build_vendor='unknown'
cross_compiling='yes'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE_TARNAME}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
enable_lock_elision=''
exceptions=''
exec_prefix='NONE'
fno_unit_at_a_time=''
force_install=''
gnu89_inline=''
hardcoded_path_in_tests=''
have_libaudit=''
have_libcap=''
have_selinux=''
host='x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu'
host_alias='x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu'
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='linux-gnu'
host_vendor='buildroot'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
ldd_rewrite_script=''
libc_cv_Bgroup=''
libc_cv_cc_loop_to_function=''
libc_cv_cc_nofma=''
libc_cv_cc_submachine=''
libc_cv_cc_with_libunwind=''
libc_cv_forced_unwind='yes'
libc_cv_fpie=''
libc_cv_gcc_static_libgcc=''
libc_cv_gcc_unwind_find_fde=''
libc_cv_hashstyle=''
libc_cv_localedir=''
libc_cv_localstatedir=''
libc_cv_nss_crypt=''
libc_cv_output_format=''
libc_cv_pic_default=''
libc_cv_rootsbindir=''
libc_cv_rtlddir=''
libc_cv_slibdir=''
libc_cv_ssp='no'
libc_cv_sysconfdir=''
libc_cv_z_combreloc=''
libc_cv_z_execstack=''
libc_extra_cflags=''
libc_extra_cppflags=''
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
link_obsolete_rpc=''
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mach_interface_list=''
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
multi_arch=''
old_glibc_headers=''
oldest_abi=''
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/usr'
profile=''
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
shared=''
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sizeof_long_double=''
static=''
static_nss=''
subdirs=' '
submachine=''
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
sysdeps_add_ons=''
sysheaders=''
sysnames=''
target_alias='x86_64-buildroot-linux-gnu'
use_default_link=''
use_ldconfig=''
use_nscd=''
with_fp='yes'

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME "GNU C Library"
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME "glibc"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "(see version.h)"
#define PACKAGE_STRING "GNU C Library (see version.h)"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT "http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/"
#define PACKAGE_URL "http://www.gnu.org/software/glibc/"
#define PKGVERSION "(Buildroot) "
#define REPORT_BUGS_TO "<http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/bugs.html>"

configure: exit 1
```

I am using ubuntu 14.04
Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the contents of `config.log`